# Accidentally deleted Ambiance theme

Tags: ambiance

I can still use Ambiance, but in the appearance windows it reads: "This theme cannot be displayed as it should, as the needed GTK+-theme 'Ambiance' is not installed"

Where can I download it or fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Install (or reinstall) the Ubuntu 'light-themes' package.  From a terminal prompt, issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes
```

That should put you back in business.

Comment: Now I can select Ambiance as the "window contents"-theme again, but I still get this error : http://ubuntuone.com/p/w1H/

Comment: Can you translate the error message for me?

Comment: "This theme cannot be displayed as it should, as the needed GTK+-theme 'Ambiance' is not installed"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge light-themes` and `sudo apt-get install light-themes`.

Comment: That didn't work either. Are there settings which aren't deleted if I purge the package, maybe in my home folder?

Answer (score 3):

Found a Solution: I used a  theme, which also was called Ambiance, so there were some config files in `.themes/Ambiance` which were unnecessary. I deleted them and everything's fine.